# Angular UI Google Maps - ng-class on map-markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I am using Angular-UI with google maps to render a Google Map (https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps).

I have two lists that are bound to the same $scope array, and I'm trying to make it so that when the mouse is hovered over an item on the list, the corresponding google map marker will be highlighted with ng-class. Unfortunately, the Angular Google Maps Documentation is really unclear about this, and I haven't been able to find any examples.

My list items:

`<div class="container-fluid" id="homeFeed">
      <div class="col-sm-6 feed-div" ng-repeat="timeslot in timeslots | filter:timeslotFilters" ng-click="">
        <md-card class="w3-hover-shadow" ng-mouseenter="timeslot.isActive=true" ng-mouseleave="timeslot.isActive=false">`

The corresponding Google Map Markers:

`<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" options="map.options">
      <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="timeslot in timeslots | filter:timeslotFilter"
        idKey="timeslot._id"
        coords="{latitude: timeslot.placeLat, longitude: timeslot.placeLong}"
        options="{icon: markerIcon(timeslot.category)}"
        ng-mouseenter="timeslot.isActive=true" ng-mouseleave="timeslot.isActive=false"
        ng-class="{'active':timeslot.isActive}">
      </ui-gmap-marker>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>`

Thanks!

Comment: May be this could help you: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1139 
And by the way, angular google maps have a separate directive for markers array - ui-gmap-markers - https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers